# Set weird behavior (python)

Tags: python

```
def _get_apps(path):
    """gets only all the apps"""

    return {app for app in os.listdir(path) if ".py" not in app}

apps = _get_apps(r"C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\Test")
css_apps = _get_apps(r"C:\Users\Hello\Desktop\Test2")

print(apps.difference(css_apps))
```

I'm trying to get the difference between two folders in my desktop. using the code above

individually the output is right it returns a set as expected

**individual print:**

```
print(apps)

print(css_apps)
```

**Output:**

```
{Music}

{Music,Css}
```

however doing:

```
print(apps.difference(css_apps))
```

**Output**:

```
set()
```

whats going on?

it returned a set as expected but somehow I can't do set operations on the returned set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `difference` operation calculates the elements which are in `apps` set but not in `css_apps` set. Now there are no elements satisfying this criteria so you get an empty set.

[`s.difference(t)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) creates a :

> new set with elements in `s` but not in `t`

Perhaps, what you need is [`.symmetric_difference()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects). This will create a new set with elements in either of the sets but not both.

```
In [1]: s1 = set([1]) # First set

In [2]: s2 = set([1,2]) # Second set

In [3]: s1.difference(s2) # Creates a new set with elements in s1 but not in s2
Out[3]: set() # empty because no elements satisfy this criteria

In [4]: s2.difference(s1)  # Creates a new set with elements in s2 but not in s1
Out[4]: {2} # element '2' exists in s2 but not in s1

In [5]: s1.symmetric_difference(s2) # Returns new set with elements in either s1 or s2 but not both
Out[5]: {2}

In [6]: s2.symmetric_difference(s1)
Out[6]: {2}
```

Comment: Perhaps suggest `symmetric_difference` as an alternative to `difference`. (Whether or not `symmetric_difference` would help depends on what will be done with the result.)

Comment: I thought order didn't matter for difference. my bad

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that's what I was looking. so now I understand what symmetric difference is. the difference between the two sets regardless of which is the order of the set compared

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks for the suggestion, updated the ans.